# How can I remove the spacing between tables in Outlook?

Tags: css, line, border, spacing

I'm trying to create this email template and I've been scratching my head but can't seem to figure out how to get rid of the 2 white lines and the space in the attached image. When I view the code in a browser, it works fine, but it doesn't appear as intended in Outlook.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

[image]

```css
body {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<table class="row row-2" align="center" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="height: 74px; width: 100%;">
  <tbody>
    <tr style="height: 74px;">
      <td style="height: 74px;">
        <table class="row-content stack" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-table-rspace: 0; background-color: #fff; color: #000; width: 650px;" width="650">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class="column column-1" width="100%" style="mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-table-rspace: 0; font-weight: 400; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 15px; border: 0;">
                <table class="image_block" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-table-rspace: 0;">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td style="width: 100%; padding-right: 0; padding-left: 0;">
                        <div align="center" style="line-height: 15px;">
                          <a href="http://www.media-nexus.com/" style="outline: 0;" tabindex="-1"><img src="https://www.media-nexus.com/images/site/logos/media-nexus-logo-320x55.png" style="display: block; height: auto; border: 0; width: 200px; max-width: 100%;" width="200" alt="Logo" title="Logo" /></a>
                        </div>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table class="row row-3" align="center" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table class="image_block" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-table-rspace: 0;">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td style="width: 100%; padding-right: 0; padding-left: 0;">
                <div align="center" style="line-height: 0px;"><img src="https://www.media-nexus.com/images/site/articles/headers/conference_room4.jpg" style="display: block; height: auto; border: 0; width: 650px; max-width: 100%;" width="650" alt="Header" title="Header" /></div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I'm also having this issue, wondering if you already resolved this?